# Spring Boot & RabbitMQ: message conversion content type

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, msgpack

We are using Spring Boot 2.1.3.RELEASE and RabbitMQ. MessagePack is used for serialization.

We are using convertAndSend:

```
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("exchange", "routingKey", object);
```

And getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
    at org.msgpack.jackson.dataformat.MessagePackFactory.createGenerator(MessagePackFactory.java:102)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:3219)
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.createMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:259)
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.toMessage(AbstractMessageConverter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.toMessage(AbstractMessageConverter.java:58)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertMessageIfNecessary(RabbitTemplate.java:1726)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:1048)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:1041)
```

This is the line where the exception is thrown:

```
return getRequiredMessageConverter().toMessage(object, new MessageProperties());
```

Is there a way to set the content type in `MessageProperties` to `application/json`?  The default is `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: MessagePack is not JSON. If you serialize using MP you have to deserialize using MP, too. [The discussion about the mimetype of MP seems to be open.](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/issues/194)